# Python why i got no output here

Tags: python, function, return, yield

I recently started learning python and I cannot figure why I got no output from the code below:

```
def countdown():
    i = 5
    while i > 0:
        return i
        i -= 1
    print (i)
```

Comment: `return i` bails out before the first iteration ends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @alfasin stated in the comments, you bail out of the function by using `return` before your function does anything.

What you probably intended to do was this:

```
def countdown():
    i = 5
    while i > 0:
        print(i)
        i -= 1

    return i
```

Then call the function:

```
countdown()
```

Output:

```
5
4
3
2
1
```